# Построение правильной кривой Безье

Tags: java

Нужно сделать правильный расчёт для построения кривой Безье. Кривая не должна ложиться на компоненты, а должна огибать их. На скриншоте - как нужно. Ну и плюс тот алгоритм, по которому сейчас строится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Path2D.Float path = new Path2D.Float();

List<Point2D.Float> points = заполняю лист точками;
 for (int i = 3; i < points.size(); i += 3)
  {
    path.curveTo(points.get(i - 2).x, points.get(i - 2).y, points.get(i - 1).x, points.get(i - 1).y, points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
  }
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Что собственно не получается-то сделать? Или вы хотите чтобы сделали за вас?

Comment: Мне кажется чтобы огибать компоненты, как минимум нужно знать координаты их границ